# Add item to ListBox from GridView

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a *ListBox* present in Home page which is populated from database .
The Home page `home.aspx` also has an `<iframe>` which is loaded with another page which displays a *GridView*.

The *GridView* has option to Add item to a table `m_my_table`.

This same table `m_my_table` is *DataSource* of list-box present in Home page `home.aspx`.

How can I add item to *ListBox* as soon as item is added in *GridView*? 
Please help in doing this with or without page Reload.

How can O call listbox databind( ) function in homepage after gridview databinding function has been called in iframe page.

Comment: did you tried update panel ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whenever item is inserted into the gridview , get that selected item and typecast into particular type and then add to your list.Remember , when item is insert into grid , the row is selected already because focus is on that row where you are inserting .